# Deal with images inside ng-repeat

Tags: image, caching

I have a template like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
   <img ng-src="{{product.imageURL}}" />
    .....
</div>
```

Each time this is regenerated it results in the browser clearing out the img and placing it back in again and will therefore redownload from source ( total size of transferred files keep increasing each time I switch from other state to this one, and i clearly can see that requests to image url are made again in Chrome Developper Tool ).

Is there a way to tell angular : " If you see that it's the same image url, do not redownload it between states". Some sort of caching ? I thought that browsers did this natively, but it doesnt seem to be the case here.

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: Chrome, but this is the same behavior with Firefox, Safari and Opera.
Is it specific to me ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31160518/caching-images-in-angularjs-ngrepeat

Comment: I don't think this more about Angular, have you enabled caching on server side? the request should return `304 not modified` status if same image file has been cached.

Comment: Issue has nothing to do with angular or even javascript. Are you running `cache disabled` in dev tools?

Comment: Thank you @MarkoCen and charlietfl ! My media server was in dev mode, so caching was disabled ;)